JavaScript click() method not working on Microsoft Edge
I've been trying to fire a click event on page load with the code below


window.onload = function () {
  var click = document.querySelector('li[data-filter=".architecture"]');
  console.log(click)
  if (click) {
    click.click()
  }
}
<li data-filter=".architecture" onclick="alert('clicked')">Item</li>



In Chrome the above code works just fine, although in Microsoft Edge the click() method does not seem to work for some reason.
Doing console.log it displays the element in all the browsers I have tried (including Microsoft Edge) and they do not display any errors.
Microsoft Edge Version: 124.0.2478.67 (Official build) (64-bit)

why do you wait for window onload if you're not handling external resources? Have you tried to use the DOMContentLoaded Event or just put yout scripts right before the closing BODY tag or by using the defer script attribute?

I test your code in the same version of Edge and it works fine. It will show the clicked alert when I run the code: https://i.sstatic.net/AJXUszJ8.png. If you just run the code snippet in your question in Edge, will it show the clicked alert? Will the code work if you run it in Edge InPrivate window?

window.onload event waits for the entire page, including its stylesheets, images, subframes, and other assets to load completely before executing your JavaScript code and that could result in a couple of issues like the one you mention. Latency could also be a factor.
You might want to try a more modern approach such as DOMContentLoaded
Here is a revision to your code that might do the trick for you:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var click = document.querySelector('li[data-filter=".architecture"]');
    
    if (click) {
        click.click();
    }
});


Just to add to this, as a recommendation, click is not probably a good name for this variable. maybe arquitectureListElement or something more specific

As others have mentioned, fire the click event after the DOMContentLoaded event.
Here is a reusable function for triggering a click event for a given selector:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  triggerClick('li[data-filter=".architecture"]');
});

function triggerClick(selector) {
  document.querySelector(selector)
    ?.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    }));
}
<li data-filter=".architecture" onclick="console.log('clicked')">Item</li>



